# EF core 2 ASP.NET intermittent network errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have a EF Core 2 Dbcontext injected in the usual way into all Controllers of a Web API:

```
services.AddDbContext<KpiContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(config.ConnectionStrings.KpiDB,
                       providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
```

This is injected into controllers in the standard way as, say, `kpidb`
and then it's passed to a static method which does this:

```
somestaticmethod(KpiContext kpidb) {
  // create something
  kpidb.Add(something);
  kpidb.SaveChanges();
}
```

This `SaveChanges()` intermittently fails with:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL
Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
Server/Instance Specified)
```

I can't see a pattern to this but it happens quite often, perhaps around 10% of the time. I've tried:

- `AddDbContextPool` instead of `AddDbContext`
- Using Transient scope for the context
- simultaneous ping shows no network interruptions at time of failure
- Using port for SQL instance to prevent enumeration makes no difference
- Simple connect and SELECT every 2 seconds script from the source to target never fails

Nothing seems to make a difference. I know that DBContext isn't thread safe but there are no async EF calls to fall foul of.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: That error you are getting means that it cannot connect to SQL Server (it might be having intermittent server issues), so I think that's the issue rather than anything with your code.

Comment: I agree with @DavidGrace. You could also create your custom execution strategy and collect more information about the issue.

Comment: Hmm, i was sceptical about this as these errors tend to be misleading. I was thinking it was something to do with the DBContext state or pool use etc. but perhaps you are right. It would be odd though since the DB in question is the main PROD db which a lot of people use and I am sure there would be more shouting.